# NetSuite Create Invoice with Paid Status

Tags: integration, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to create an invoice, in NetSuite, that has a status of "Paid in Full."  We have a new department that will be processing their payments in an external system, and I just need to get them into NetSuite, for the GL.

So far, I have not founda  way to set the status to paid ("CustInvc:B").  I've also found nothing on the Suite Answers site, or via an initial call to NetSuite.  I'm waiting for their account department to call me back; but, I figured I may have more luck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really recommend closing the loop here and getting payment status back from that external system into Netsuite. Then script that information to create the appropriate payment records in Netsuite and apply them to the Invoices.

It's generally not a huge amount of work as long as the external system can receive and return a reference (just the Invoice Document Number or internal id) to the Netsuite invoice.

Having feedback allows you to track customer balances and aging and provides the possibility of having your AR be accurate.

Comment: You should absolutely create the appropriate transactions to achieve the appropriate status. Typically, particularly on transactions, the Status fields are read-only and you cannot set them explicitly, except to skip any Approval states.

Comment: Thanks @bknights.  We are receiving all of that information, from the external system.  That is what I'm using to create the invoice.  Initially our AR department said they did not want anything other than a paid invoice record (solely to give the ability to refund a customer, if needed).  From the responses, it looks like the payment and invoice will be needed, to make it happen.  Thanks!

Comment: Once you have the invoice you can (in SS 1.0) use `nlapiTransformRecord('invoice', invoiceid, 'customerpayment');` to get an initialized payment record

Answer (score 1):

In NetSuite an invoice isn't "Paid in Full" until the balance is zero. You need to create a payment record for the invoice to mirror the payments accepted in the external system. Once the value of the payments (there can be more than one) zero out the value of the invoice, it will say "Paid in Full"